# Java script scroll highlighting not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

So I am trying to build my website, and I have a very nice sticky header and I am trying to get a sort of scroll spy kind of effect, with out using bootstrap. 
I would like the current section of the navigation being viewd to be highlighted with an active class if that makes sense.

The problem is, I have 0 jquery knowledge, and so I copied some code from a youtube video, but I cant implement it effectively. Could someone correct this query code so it highlights in the navigation bar, the section currently being viewd, and updates as a user scrolls to another section, and thus that section is highlighted in the nav bar?

Ps - I repeat, I do NOT want anything to do with bootstrap xD

HERE is my code pen link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZmRZN

```
Any help would be amazing!
```

Comment: 1) your codepen doesn't load, 2) when I fixed one obvious error in the codepen, 20 more popped up, 3) what errors do **you** observe in your browsers developer tools console, 4) not even sure what a **"scroll spy kind of effect"** even means. and 5) `Could someone correct this query code` - indeed, can you post this so called `query code` in the question and explain what you want corrected in the code

Comment: Your "scrollspy" works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to put `$`for calling jQuery before `(function() {`. although it doesnt show well on snippet but i tried it on my server and works fine~try it on your server :)

```js
$(function() {
 var navLinks = $('nav ul li a'),
   navH = $('nav').height(),
   section = $('section'),
   documentEl = $(document);

 documentEl.on('scroll', function() {
   var currentScrollPos = documentEl.scrollTop();

   section.each(function() {
     var self = $(this);
     if ( self.offset().top < (currentScrollPos + navH) && (currentScrollPos + navH) < (self.offset().top + self.outerHeight()) ) {
       var targetClass = '.' + self.attr('class') + '-marker';
       navLinks.removeClass('active');
       $(targetClass).addClass('active');
     }
   });

 });
})();
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  /*reset*/
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: medium none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42rem;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
button{
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
a{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/*End Reset*/

/*Fonts*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bebas_neuebold';
  src:  url('../fonts/bebasneue_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bebas_neuebook';
  src:  url('../fonts/bebasneue_book-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue_book-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bebas_neuelight';
  src:  url('../fonts/bebasneue_light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue_light-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bebas_neue_regularregular';
  src:  url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bebas_neuethin';
  src:  url('../fonts/bebasneue_thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue_thin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
  src:  url('../fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
.bebas-bold{
 font-family: bebas_neuebold !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.bebas-book{
 font-family: bebas_neuebook !important;
}
.bebas-light{
 font-family: bebas_neuelight !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.bebas-thin{
  font-family: bebas_neuethin !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.bebas-reg{
 font-family: bebas_neue_regularregular !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
/*End fonts*/
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #505050;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/*Header*/
#navwrapper{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
li img {
 height:95px;
 width:95px;
}

ul{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.topnav {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggleNavButton {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  /*left: 50%;*/
  top: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.toggleNavButton:before,
.toggleNavButton:after {
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
}
.toggleNavButton:after {
  top: 20px;
}
.toggleNavButton.active {
  width: 0;
}
.toggleNavButton.active:after {
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.toggleNavButton.active:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/* Float the list items side by side */
nav ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

.padnav{
  padding: 0px 35px 0px 35px;
  margin-top:35px;
}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
nav ul li.padnav a:hover {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s; /* Safari */
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #2098D1;

}

.active{
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s; /* Safari */
  transition: 0.1s;;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #2098D1;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 680 (changed to 770 to accomodate) pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }

  ul.topnav li:nth-child(1){
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }

  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
  }
  ul.topnav li{
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
  ul.topnav a{
    margin-top: 25px !important;
    margin-right: 25px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
  }

  li img {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav{
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  #navhit{
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -8px;
  }

  li.padnav{
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }

  ul.topnav li.padnav a:hover {
    border: none !important;
  }

  #navwrapper{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
/*sections*/
section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100vh;
}

section.landing{
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

section.about{
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

section.project{
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

section.blog{
  background-color: #95a5a6;
}

section.contact{
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}

.landing{
  height: 95vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navwrapper">
 <nav class="navbar bebas-reg container">
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <li class="padnav"><a href="about.html" class="about-marker active">About</a></li>
   <li class="padnav"><a href="projects.html" class="proj-marker">Projects</a></li>
   <li class="logo"><img src="img/logo-black.png"></img></li>
   <li class="padnav"><a href="contact" class="contact-marker">Contact</a></li>
   <li class="padnav"><a href="blog" class="blog-marker">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>


<section class="landing">
 <h1> landing </h1>
</section>

<section class="about">
 <h1> about </h1>
</section>

<section class="proj">
 <h1> proj </h1>
</section>

<section class="contact">
 <h1> contact </h1>
</section>

<section class="blog">
 <h1> blog </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have cried so much over this. Your explanation and code was amazing :)